# sshd_config ForceCommand /usr/bin/rsync error "connection unexpectedly closed"

Tags: ssh, rsync

How should ForceCommand be configured in order to allow the backup user to execute any rsync command? With ForceCommand set to /usr/bin/rsync I receive the error below: connection unexpectedly closed...

/etc/ssh/sshd_config on remote server hosting the files to be copied from:

```
Match User backup
    PasswordAuthentication no  
    PubkeyAuthentication yes  
    AllowTCPForwarding no  
    X11Forwarding no  
    ForceCommand /usr/bin/rsync
```

rsync command running on the local server doing the copying from the remote server:

```
rsync -avzh --progress backup@hostname.domain:/opt/backups/automatic/cron/mysql/ /tmp/.  

rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [Receiver=3.0.7]
```

---

If I configure ForceCommand to the exact rsync command such as the one below I am able to remotely rsync successfully as the backup user but for this project I don't want to have to use the full exact command as below:

```
ForceCommand /usr/bin/rsync --server --sender -vlwkDonecf.iLew . /opt/backups/automatic/cron/mysql/
```

---

If I configure ForceCommand to use a script such as the one below I am able to remotely rsync successfully. I'm curious why this works and /usr/bin/rsync doesn't?

```
Match User backup
    PasswordAuthentication no  
    PubkeyAuthentication yes  
    AllowTCPForwarding no  
    X11Forwarding no  
    ForceCommand /home/backup/cron/validate-rsync
```

The validate-rsync script:

```
#!/bin/sh   
#script to validate rsync  
#script source: http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/#validate-rsync  

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in   
*\&*)   
echo "Rejected"   
;;   
*\(*)   
echo "Rejected"   
;;   
*\{*)   
echo "Rejected"   
;;   
*\;*)   
echo "Rejected"   
;;   
*\<*)   
echo "Rejected"   
;;   
*\`*)   
echo "Rejected"   
;;   
*\|*)   
echo "Rejected"   
;;   
rsync\ --server*)   
$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND   
;;   
*)   
echo "Rejected"   
;;   
esac
```

---

My primary question is why doesn't ForceCommand /usr/bin/rsync work?

I'm also curious about the best way(s) to do this. I can't chroot the backup user because I'm copying from several different folders. I don't really want to have to use the full exact rsync --server --client etc. command because I'm copying several different folders and that seems excessive. I'm curious about the simplest/best way(s) to restrict the backup user to rsync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *why* is easy... `ForceCommand` does exactly what it says:  You connect, it forces you to run that command no matter what you actually wanted to do.  In this case, that command is  `/usr/bin/rsync` with no flags.

`rsync` works by running another copy of `rsync` on the other side of the connection and talking to it over ssh.  In this case though, it's unable to start the other side with the flags it needs because the command is replaced by `/usr/bin/rsync`

Your rsync-validate script is probably the best way to go about this.  It checks the request to make sure it is a valid rsync server command, and only then does it run it.  `rsync` probably *could* be modified to check the $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND directly when its run without arguments, but there's probably a good security reason not to do so.

Answer (score 3):

The `ForceCommand` option is meant to be used with a command that specifically understands that it's acting as an [SSH gatekeeper](https://calomel.org/openssh.html). The original command is placed in the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable.

Comment: It sounds like in the case of ForceCommand internal-sftp, internal-sftp understands that it's acting as an SSH gatekeeper? In contrast with ForceCommand /usr/bin/rsync whereas it sounds like ForceCommand /usr/bin/rsync doesn't understand that it's acting as an SSH gatekeeper and thus a script is required and use of $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND is required?

Comment: Yes, sort of. Internal subsystems are a special case. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have `ForceCommand` work with *any* rsync command, but you can make it work with one.  From the client, you can run:

```
rsync -azh -e 'ssh -v' backup@hostname.domain:/opt/backups/automatic/cron/mysql/ /tmp/.
```

To get the serverside command.  You'll see it in the verbose output after the key exchange but before the copying starts:

```
...
debug1: Sending command: rsync --server -vlogDtprz --delete . /tmp
...
```

And then you can add that to your `ForceCommand`:

```
ForceCommand rsync --server -vlogDtprz --delete . /tmp
```

source: [Sakana.fr: Securing automated rsync over SSH](http://www.sakana.fr/blog/2008/05/07/securing-automated-rsync-over-ssh/)